# Sync renamed folders, moved files?

Tags: windows, sync, file-management

I have two drives (G: and H:, let's say) each with a copy of my \Photos directory tree. (On Windows 10.)

- I've been actively working in the H: copy (edits, etc.). Plus:
- have renamed some sub-directories to be more descriptive ("2009\2009-01-01" to "2009\20090101 New Years Day")
- split some directories into multiple directories (20090704 Fireworks and 20090704 Cookout)

I am trying to set up automatic syncing with FreeFileSync from H: to X:, a NAS drive. I don't really need G:, but first want to ensure that I'm not missing any files that may have inadvertently ended up on G: only.

So I'm trying to do this with FreeFileSync but its synchronization of moved files doesn't seem like exactly what I need (maybe I'm wrong about this). Any suggestions for a way to identify suspected file moves and renamed directories and apply the same moves to the target (G:)?

(There are several hundred folders, otherwise I'd bite the bullet and do it manually.)

Answer (score 2):

You can try these commerical programs. They can detect renamed/moved files/folders
- [GoodSync](https://www.goodsync.com/)

> File and Folder Move/Rename Detection:
>   GoodSync detects file/folder renames and executes them as Move commands.

- [Syncovery](https://www.syncovery.com/)

> Detects Moved Files:
>   If you reorganized your folders by moving files
>   to different locations, Syncovery will detect this and quickly perform
>   the same moves on the other side of the sync, rather than deleting and
>   re-copying the files.

- [Bvckup](https://bvckup2.com/)

> When a file is moved or renamed at the source, this change should
>   ideally be replicated by simply moving the corresponding files at the
>   destination.

Make sure you test those programs before using them for your real data.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried both **GoodSync** and **Syncovery** and more, with that, the best for far was: **freefilesync** for its simple and easy to use user interface.
and by using it you can use the mirror setting which enables move detect feature. here is some useful explains:

1. https://freefilesync.org/manual.php?topic=synchronization-settings
2. https://freefilesync.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4542

---

Update 09.11.2021, synctoy 2.1v was better for me because freefilesync sometimes missed the edited files and recopy&delete them.
you can get it from:

1. https://www.filecroco.com/download-synctoy/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).